# recursive image manipulation (Canvas, HTML5, Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, graphics, canvas

I’m trying to use Canvas for a fractal algorithm that requires one to draw something, then capture that image, draw some mangled copies of it, then capture *that* image, etc. I’m running into a problem, though, because toDataURL() seems to be causing a failure in either the clear screen command ("clearRect") or the restore transformation matrix command ("restore").

The code below is intended to draw a black square, then copy the canvas to a variable named “img”, translate down and to the right, then paste “img” to the new position. The result should be two squares.  But instead it’s first 1 square, then 2 squares, then 3, then 4 … (Then it goes out of bounds, but presumably it’s still copying squares off the page.)

Any help will be greatly, greatly appreciated.

Here's a link to the code in action: https://www.msu.edu/~brown202/dataURLproblem.html

Here's the code:

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <script type="application/x-javascript">
                function draw() {
                    var canvas = document.getElementById("fractal");
                    if (canvas.getContext) {
                        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
                        var img;
                        ctx.clearRect(0,0,400,400);    // clear the canvas, which measures 400 by 400
                        ctx.fillRect (0,0,100,100);    // draw a square
                        ctx.save();
                            img = canvas.toDataURL();    // store the canvas image in "img"
                            ctx.translate(100,100);      // shift picture
                            ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0);    // draw the stored image of the canvas in the new place
                        ctx.restore();
                    }
                }
                function init() {
                    setInterval(draw,500);          // repeat every 500 ms.
                }
            </script>
        </head>
        <body onload="init();">
            <canvas id="fractal" width="400" height="400">
                <p>This animation requires a browser that supports the
                <a href="http://www.w3.org/html/wg/html5/">HTML5</a> 
                &lt;canvas&gt; feature.</p>
            </canvas>
        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: You passed `draw` to `setInterval` so it will call this forever.  What exactly do you want to do?  Draw two squares only?

Comment: Yes, that's intentional.  It's redrawing the scene every 500 ms.  It should draw the same picture -- just two squares -- each time.  But instead it adds a square each time it's called.

Comment: Do you want it to draw only the same two squares?  Or smaller squares?  What figure are you trying to draw?

Comment: I was trying to draw two squares, by first drawing one, then copying the entire canvas and redrawing the canvas somewhere else.  The image wasn't really the point, though -- the point was I wanted to capture the image on the canvas, manipulate it, and then draw it back onto the canvas.

Happily, jimr's response totally nailed it.

Answer (score 6):

If you look at the javascript console when your page runs, it's generating errors:

> Uncaught TypeError: Type error

This is because you're trying to pass a string (the `dataURL` version of the image) to `drawImage` when the `drawImage` function is expecting an image/canvas.

The `drawImage` function can take in a `canvas` element as its argument, which will do what you want.

Instead of doing:

```
img = canvas.toDataURL();
ctx.drawImage(img, 0,0);
```

Just do:

```
ctx.drawImage(canvas, 0,0);
```

Comment: And here's a fiddle for it (with a smaller square for fun): http://jsfiddle.net/r7veu/ (+1 to jimr)